# How can I load from a JS Stream(integrating with existing app)? not JS Bundle file path

Tags: react-native

I found that react-native load react Js from android's default file directory,I want a api to load react Js from a stream, not file path. so I can load Js from a network server instead of putting a Js bundle file in local directory.

```
 String sdDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    String bundleFile = sdDir + "/Download/ReactNativeDevBundle.js";
    mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
            .setApplication(getApplication())
            .setJSBundleFile(bundleFile)
            .addPackage(new MainReactPackage())
            .setUseDeveloperSupport(false)
            .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
            .build();
    mReactRootView.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager, "MyAwesomeApp", null);
    setContentView(mReactRootView);
```

Library version : react-native:0.15.0

I can change the default load directory, but I can not change the file name. And I found no way to load Js from a stream.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue i was face recently and fixed this issue.I am late to answer this question may b it will help someone.

When we try to load the index.android.bunddle from asset folder it search to the path drawable-mdpi folder whatever the image name you gave in react native folder it creates  the images in drawable folders.

And pick that image and show to us.In case of server index.android.bundle we store that file in mob devices so it cant find the images in storage Our storage not contains the drawable folders.
So the solution is we need to create the density drawable folders like drawable-mdpi  to mobile storage parallel to the index.android.bundle and write the images in that folder.

here is my code snippets

```
    int lengthOfFile = connection.getContentLength();
    //            InputStream input= new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(),lengthOfFile);
                input = connection.getInputStream();
    //            FileOutputStream 

outPut=context.openFileOutput("index.android.bundle",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                FileOutputStream outPut = null;
                File directory,file;

     directory = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "drawable-xxhdpi");
                        if(!directory.exists()){
                            directory.mkdir();
                        }
  file = new File(context.getFilesDir() + File.separator + "drawable-xxhdpi", "src_components_images_iconthumbsdowndefault.png");
                        outPut = new FileOutputStream(file);

      byte data[]=new byte[4096];
                long total=0;
                int x = 0;
                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1){
                    total+=count;
                    x++;
    //                publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lengthOfFile));
                    outPut.write(data,0,count);
                }
                outPut.flush();
                outPut.close();
                input.close();
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: Yes, Thats correct  There is not any explanation in documentation about this topic. All we did is RnD